# Tokbox Opentok error - OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError Permission Denied on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opentok, tokbox

We are using https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js

Facing intermittent issues while using Google Chrome v47.0.2

As soon as the session is connected, without showing the permission dialog, the browser directly throws an access denied message (cannot access microphone or camera) with this error in the console "OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError Permission Denied" . This error has started occurring recently - mid-December.

We tried exploring the issue on various forums including this one. We could only come up with this post - https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205065196-displaying-error-opentok-min-js-64-1500-Session-publish-OT-Publisher-Access-Denied-Permission-Denied-End-user-denied-permission-to-hardware-devices-?input_string=OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError%20Permission%20Denied%20on%20Chrome

But, it's irrelevant, since we are using https for all our application requests.

Please help as we are stuck on the production environment with this bug.

Comment: By default, Chrome will remember whatever permission choice the user made. Have you tried going into the Content -> Media settings in Chrome and removing the "deny" permission that is stored? Are you saying this is intermittent because it happens randomly and then goes back to working as expected randomly?

Comment: Hi Ankur, so we did check the preferences, it is set to "always allowed"! the issue randomly starts on a few machines and then this happens continually on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using moderator or publisher as role when creating your token? use session.generateToken() to generate a token every time a new user gets online, example on nodejs https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/node/

please see error # 1500 here https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Error.html for more information